# image not displaying in windows after creating doc file using laravel

Tags: excel, laravel

I have generated a doc file using laravel.In doc file i need to display images also.images is displaying in ubuntu but not displaying in windows.I was converted images to base64 encoded.

```
$body_content = "<p>description<img alt="" src="https://staging-sub.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/20231102132857p11UD.jpg" style="height:333px; width:500px" />";
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($body_content);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        // Find all img elements in the HTML
        $imgElements = $xpath->query('//img');
        foreach ($imgElements as $imgElement) {
            // Get the src attribute value
            $src = $imgElement->getAttribute('src');

            // Fetch the image data from the URL
            $imageData = file_get_contents($src);

            if ($imageData !== false) {
                // Encode the image data as a base64 string
                $base64ImageData = base64_encode($imageData);

                // Replace the src attribute with the base64 data
                $imgElement->setAttribute('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . $base64ImageData);
            }
        }
        // Get the modified HTML content
        $modifiedHtml = $dom->saveHTML();

        $body_content = $modifiedHtml;

        $fileName = Str::random() . time() . '.doc';
        $fullpath = $folderName . '/' . $fileName;

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($fullpath, $body_content, [
        'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName,
        'ContentType' => 'application/msword'
    ]);

    // Get the URL of the saved file
    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fullpath);
    Storage::disk(config("filesystems.default"))->download($fullpath);
```

Comment: What is the error you are recieving?

Comment: @Adi download is working fine..but image is not displaying.Only text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code.Now it working both windows and linux

```
    $dom->loadHTML($body_content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // Find all img elements in the HTML
    $imgElements = $xpath->query('//img');
    foreach ($imgElements as $imgElement) {
        // Get the src attribute value
        $src = $imgElement->getAttribute('src');

        // Fetch the image data from the URL
        $imageData = file_get_contents($src);

        if ($imageData !== false) {
            // Encode the image data as a base64 string
            $base64ImageData = base64_encode($imageData);

            // Replace the src attribute with the base64 data
            $imgElement->setAttribute('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . $base64ImageData);
        }
    }
    // Get the modified HTML content
    $modifiedHtml = $dom->saveHTML();
```